# Angular $cookieStore for Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

im creating a add to cart application with the use of ionicframework with angular.
im trying to use the angular `ngCookies` in my controller

My application doesn't load when i add the  `ngCookies` in my controller in this way

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCookies'])
```

But my application works when i dont include `ngCookies` in this way

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
```

and i also have included the `<script src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>` in my ionic index.html page

I dont know if im missing anything anywhere

Comment: Did you add angular-cookies.js after angular.js? If so, what errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: this is the http://plnkr.co/edit/BLJ83zdLkdEgYSFgkFoK?p=preview  im using it.
i get undefined values when i retrieve the cookie values

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a main module for the app. Something like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
```

try to inject the reference there:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCookies', 'starter.controllers'])
```

and leave your controller module as it was before:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
```

always check what kind of error messages in chrome (console).

Comment: This shall be your issue. Inject first your newly added module ngCookies to your app before being able to inject it into your controllers & services

Comment: I just confirm that your analysis may be the right one. 1- inject module to app. If needed, inject the module to a controller.